# Large dimension design in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008, dimensional-modeling

I have a fact table with 100 millions+ rows and with 4 dimensions and everything works fine from query performance point of view and from processing cube perspective (~it takes around 5-6 minutes to process the cube).

1/ Now I have to add a new dimension with 6 millions rows. The cube processing time will explode?

2/ Is that a good practice? Do I have other alternatives to model this dimension?

3/ What about if my fact table raises to 300 millions rows and my dimension to 15 millions rows?

Any thought is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read through the performance guide? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17303

Comment: I have worked with a 30 million rows dimension without problems. You just have to have enough RAM for the complete dimension to fit in during processing. Else, that can get really slow.